# Exploratory data analysis before pefrorming Canonical Correspondence Analysis (CCA)

Tags: r, factor-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis, ecology, mode

I want to perform CCA, but I read that,

> remember that observations (for example, species abundances) have to present *unimodal distributions* along gradients (for example, environmental variables). Note that if observations are, instead, *linearly* related to gradients, we have to use a *Canonical Correlation Analysis (CANCOR)* or *Redundancy Analysis (RDA)* instead of a *Canonical Correspondence Analysis (CCA)*.
>    Source: [R Functions: Canonical Correspondence Analysis: CCA and Partial CCA](http://rfunctions.blogspot.com/2016/11/canonical-correspondence-analysis-cca.html)

Which exploratory data analysis I can carry out (preferably in `R`) to be sure that my data are suitable for CCA?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've slightly modified it. It's entirely statistical question, but because i'm stick with certain language, the `R` solution would be more useful just for me.